# Prevent other sessions from reading data until I'm finished

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Prevent other sessions from reading data until I'm finished

I have a table that holds customers from different companies, something like:

```
CUSTOMER
    CUSTOMER_ID
    COMPANY_ID
    CUSTOMER_NAME
    FOO_CODE
```

When I insert or update a customer I need to calculate a FOO_CODE based on existing ones (within the company).

If I simply do this:

```
SELECT MAX(FOO_CODE) AS GREATEST_CODE_SO_FAR
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE COMPANY_ID=:company_id
```

... then generate the code in the client language (PHP) and finally issue the INSERT/UPDATE I understand I can face a race condition if other program instance fetches the same `GREATEST_CODE_SO_FAR`.

**Is it possible to issue a row-level lock on the table so other sessions that attempt to read the `FOO_CODE` column of any customer that belongs to a given company are delayed until I commit or rollback my transaction?**

---

My failed attemps:

- This:

  ```
  SELECT MAX(FOO_CODE)
  FROM CUSTOMER 
  WHERE COMPANY_ID=:company_id
  FOR UPDATE
  ```

  ... triggers:

  > ORA-01786: FOR UPDATE of this query expression is not allowed
- This:

  ```
  SELECT FOO_CODE
  FROM CUSTOMER 
  WHERE COMPANY_ID=:company_id
  FOR UPDATE
  ```

  ... retrieves all company rows and does not even prevent other sessions from reading data.
- `LOCK TABLE`... well, documentation barely has any example and I can't figure out the syntax

P.S. Is it *not* an incrementing number, it's an alphanumeric string.

Comment: Do you have a unique key for the field FOO_CODE? It prevents from having the same values in this column. If you have race condition, you will restart your procedure as many times as you need to insert your values correctly. Solution with the unique key will also scale up, so, you won't have unnecessary locks and latches.

Comment: @zaratustra - I don't, but it's a glaring omission I need to fix no matter what I do next.

Comment: Also, if you don't show this field to your user you can use the function `SYS_GUID()` to generate `FOO_CODE`, it's very reliable, you can use it even in systems with the RAC architecture

Comment: I'm reading [Generating A Gap-free Series Of Numbers — Not Always A Problem](http://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/generating-a-gap-free-series-of-numbers-not-always-a-problem/) right now, looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

You can't block another session from reading data, as far as I'm aware. One of the differences between Oracle and some other databases is that writers don't block readers.

I'd probably look at this slightly differently. I'm assuming the way you generate the next `foo_code` is deterministic. If you add a unique index on `company_id, foo_code` then you can have your application attempt the insert in a loop:

- get your current max value
- calculate your new code
- do the insert
- if you don't get a constraint violation, break out of the loop
- otherwise continue to the next iteration of the loop and repeat the process

If two sessions attempt this at the same time then the second one will attempt to insert the same `foo_code` and will get a unique constraint violation. That is trapped and handled nicely and it just tries again; potentially multiple times until it gets a clean insert.

You could have a DB procedure that attempts the insert in a loop, but since you want to generate the new value in PHP then it would make sense for the loop to be in PHP too, attempting a simple insert.

This doesn't necessarily scale well if you have a high volume of inserts and clashes are likely. But if you're expecting simultaneous inserts for the same customer to be rare and just have to handle the odd occasions when it does happen this won't add much overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The unique index is something I'll need to add anyway (too bad I'm working on someone else's code and the simplest task can be daunting).